# Print RegEx matches using SED in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have an XML file, the file is made up of one line.

What I am trying to do is extract the "`finalNumber`" attribute value from the file via Putty. Rather than having to download a copy and search using notepad++.

I've built up a regular expression that I've tested on an [On-line Tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), and tried using it within a `sed` command to [duplicate grep functionality](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-15b). The command runs but doesn't return anything.

RegEx:

```
(?<=finalNumber=")(.*?)(?=")
```

`sed` Command (returns nothing, expected 28, see file extract):

```
sed -n '/(?<=finalNumber=")(.*?)(?=")/p' file.xml
```

File Extract:

```
...argo:finalizedDate="2012-02-09T00:00:00.000Z" argo:finalNumber="28" argo:revenueMonth=""...
```

I feel like I am close (i could be wrong), am I on the right lines or is there better way to achieve the output?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Nothing wrong with good old grep here.

```
grep -E -o 'finalNumber="[0-9]+"' file.xml | grep -E -o '[0-9]+'
```

Use `-E` for extended regular expressions, and `-o` to print only the matching part.

Comment: Accepted due to the fact it returns every occurrence when there a multiple matches in a file, an undocumented request.

Answer (score 13):

Though you already select an answer, here is a way you can do in pure sed:

```
sed -n 's/^.*finalNumber="\([[:digit:]]\+\)".*$/\1/p' <test
```

Output:

```
28
```

This replaces the entire line by the match number and print (because p will print the entire line so you have to replace the entire line)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.*finalNumber="([^"]*)".*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not support look-ahead assertions. Perl does, though:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /(?<=finalNumber=")(.*?)(?=")/'
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, there is no need to use look-aheads here.
Try this one

```
sed -n '/finalNumber="[[:digit:]]\+"/p'
```

Comment: That prints the whole line on  my machine.